# GROUP BY LAST DATE MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, having

I have this tables,

```
user
  id
  name

visit
  id
  id_user (fk user.id)
  date
  comment
```

If i execute this query,

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, e.id, e.date, e.comment
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN visit e ON e.id_user=u.id
```

I get,

```
1 Jhon 1 2013-12-01 '1st Comment' 
1 Jhon 2 2013-12-03 '2nd Comment' 
1 Jhon 3 2013-12-01 '3rd Comment'
```

If I `GROUP BY u.id`, then I get

```
1 Jhon 1 2013-12-01 '1st Comment'
```

I need the last visit from Jhon

```
1 Jhon 3 2013-12-04 '3rd Comment'
```

I try this

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, e.id, MAX(e.date), e.comment
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN visit e ON e.id_user=u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

And this,

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, e.id, MAX(e.date), e.comment
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN visit e ON e.id_user=u.id
GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING MAX(e.date)
```

And I get

```
1 Jhon 1 2013-12-04 '1st Comment'
```

But this is not valid to me... I need the last visit from this user

```
1 Jhon 3 2013-12-01 '3rd Comment'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the last comment for every user:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, e.id, e.date, e.comment
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t1.*
  FROM visit t1
    LEFT JOIN visit t2
      ON t1.id_user = t2.id_user AND t1.date < t2.date
  WHERE t2.id_user IS NULL
  ) e ON e.id_user=u.id
```

Comment: Thanks! For visits to the same date I added ORDER BY DESC t1.id DESC

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, e.id, e.date, e.comment
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN visit e ON e.id_user=u.id
ORDER BY e.date desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If he only wants the results for one user this is ideal, but if he wants it for more than one (which i believe he does), this will not work

Comment: Fair point. Was just going on my interpretation of the OP. Specifically "But this is not valid to me... I need the last visit from this user". So I guessed there would be a `where` clause in there somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, e.id, e.date, e.comment FROM user u LEFT JOIN visit e ON e.id_user=u.id order by e.date DESC limit 0,1
```

Will show 1 record order by date.

Hope will help!